# New File Drawable not avalaible i reference

Tags: android

Today I create a file drawable after that I check in reference use CTRL+Space new file drawable not show maybe you can have a solution for me ?

Maybe this is my code in drawable

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="oval">
</shape>
```

Comment: rebuild your project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to Use this code

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:innerRadius="0dp"
android:shape="ring"
android:thicknessRatio="2"
android:useLevel="false" >
<solid android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```